# How to display rounded values in a form and show on focus the original values?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have numeric values with many decimal places and the precision is required for other functions. I want to present the values in a form, so the user can change the values if necessary.
To increase the readability, I want to display the values rounded to 2 decimal places, but if the user clicks on an input field, the complete value should be presented. By doing this, the user can see the real value and adjust them better.

Example: 
HTML

```
<button id="myBtn" onclick="fillForm()">Try it</button>
<form id="myForm" >
 <fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="myInput1" onchange="myFunction()" >
 </fieldset>      
</form>
```

JavasSript

```
<script>
 //Example values that should be presented
 var x = 3.14159265359;

 function fillForm(){
  document.getElementbyId("myInput1").value = x;
 }
 function myFunction(){
  x = document.getElementbyId("myInput1");
 }
</script>
```

The form input value should be " 3.14 " and if the user clicks in the field, the displayed value should be 3.14159265359.

Now the user can change the value and the new value has to be saved.

Because this is for a local 1 page website with no guaranty of internet connection, it would be an asset but not a requirement, to do it without an external script (jquery …).

Comment: Do Math.round(x * 100) / 100 to display in html input and change / reassign original again on hover function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use focus and blur event to mask/unmask you float, then simply store the original value in a data param, so you can use the same function to all input in your form ;)

```js
function fillForm(inputId, val)
{
  var element = document.querySelector('#'+inputId); 
  element.value = val; 
  mask(element); 
}

function mask(element) {
 element.setAttribute('data-unmasked',element.value);
 element.value = parseFloat(element.value).toFixed(2);
 }
 
 function unmask(element) {
 element.value = element.getAttribute('data-unmasked') || '';
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="fillForm('myInput1',3.156788)">Fill!</button>
<form id="myForm" >
 <fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="myInput1" onblur="mask(this)" onfocus="unmask(this)" >
 </fieldset>      
</form>
```

Edit: added "fillForm()" :)

Comment: great solution - for my case i have to display the inertial value rounded as well, so i used:  `function fillForm(id_input, val){var id_element = document.getElementById(id_input);
id_element.value = x.toFixed(2);
id_element.setAttribute('data-unmasked',val);
}´

Comment: I suggest you to use something like ´fillForm(id_input, val){var id_element = document.getElementById(id_input); id_element.value = x; mask( id_element); }´ in this way you'll keep all the "masking code" in the same place and if you decide to modify it for some reason, you will need to modify it only once, whitout the risk of forgetting something ;)

Comment: P.s. welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I planned to mark your answer but because of the weekend break I had not enough time on friday :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.toFixed()`. It accepts one argument, an integer, and will display that many decimal points. Since Javascript primitives are immutable, your `x` variable will remain the same value. (also when getting/setting the value of an input use the `.value` property

```
 function fillForm(){
  document.getElementbyId("myInput1").value = x.toFixed(2);
 }
```

If you need to save it you can store it in a new value

`var displayX = x.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I hope you have other suggestions.

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" >
 <fieldset> 
  <input type="text" id="myInput1" >
 </fieldset>       
</form>

<button id="myBtn" onclick="fill_form()">fill form</button>
```

JavasSript

```
 <script>
 var apple_pi = 10.574148541;
 var id_form = document.getElementById("myForm");

 //Event listener for form
 id _form.addEventListener("focus", copy_input_placeh_to_val, true);
 id _form.addEventListener("blur", round_input_2decimal, true);
 id _form.addEventListener("change", copy_input_val_to_placeh, true);

 // Replace input value with input placeholder value
 function copy_input_placeh_to_val(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.placeholder; 
 }

 // Rounds calling elemet value to 2 decimal places
 function round_input_2decimal(event) {
  var val = event.target.value
 event.target.value = Number(val).toFixed(2);
 }

// Replace input placeholder value with input value
function copy_input_val_to_placeh(event) {
 event.target.placeholder = event.target.value;
}

// Fills input elements with value and placeholder value. 
// While call of function input_id_str has to be a string ->      
//fill_input_val_placeh("id", value) ;
function fill_input_val_placeh (input_id_str, val) {
 var element_id = document.getElementById(input_id_str);
 element_id.placeholder = val;
 element_id.value = val.toFixed(2);
}

// Writes a value to a form input
function fill_form(){
 fill_input_val_placeh("myInput1", apple_pi);
}
</script>
```

Here is an running example
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLDAGSRT113G

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some problems that needs to be fixed in your code:

- You are redeclaring the `x` variable inside your `myFunction` function with `var x =...`, you just need to refer the already declared `x` without the `var` keyword.
- Instead of using `document.getElementById()` in `myFunction`, pass `this` as a param in `onchange="myFunction(this)"` and get its value in the `function`.
- Use `parseFloat()` to parse the value of your input to a float, and use `.toFixed(2)` to display it as `3.14`.

This is the working code:

```
var x = 3.14159265359;

function fillForm() {
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = x.toFixed(2);
}

function myFunction(input) {
  x = parseFloat(input.value);
}
```

To display the original number when you click on the `input` you need to use the `onfocus` event, take a look at the Demo.

**Demo:**

```js
var x = 3.14159265359;

function fillForm() {
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = x.toFixed(2);
}

function focusIt(input){
    input.value = x;
}

function myFunction(input) {
  x = parseFloat(input.value);
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onclick="fillForm()">Try it</button>
<form id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" id="myInput1" onchange="myFunction(this)" onfocus="focusIt(this)">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the var error. I fixed it and it was just in the demo code. Sadly your solution doesnt work for me because i want to see all decimal places on click.

Comment: @Chrischen Well to achieve this when you click the input, you need to add an `onfocus` event, like this `onfocus="focusIt(this)"`, see my Edited Demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, I used focus and blur listeners without using jQuery.
I added an attribute to `input` named **realData**

```js
document.getElementById("myInput1").addEventListener("focus", function() {
  var realData = document.getElementById("myInput1").getAttribute("realData");
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = realData;
});

document.getElementById("myInput1").addEventListener("blur", function() {
  var realData = Number(document.getElementById("myInput1").getAttribute("realData"));
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = realData.toFixed(2);
});

function fillForm(value) {
  document.getElementById("myInput1").value = value.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("myInput1").setAttribute("realData", value);
}
 
var x = 3.14159265359;

fillForm(x);
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onclick="fillForm()">Try it</button>
<form id="myForm" >
 <fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="myInput1" realData="" onchange="myFunction()" >
 </fieldset>      
</form>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mns0gp6L/1/